# Sinch Video Chat PHP Authentication

Tags: php, mysql, sinch, sinch-verification

I have downloaded sinch video chat system,it looks promising

I have a PHP/MySQL system, in place with authenticated users, what I want is to bypass the sinch built in login/create user system and enable the user which i already forced to sign in to reach sinch chat to be able to chat directly, instead of having him login again on sinch

Help appreciated

Many Thanks

Comment: Sounds awesome. Keep us posted :p

Comment: Hello, do you have any idea about a solution? regards

Answer (score 0):

You can send in a auth ticket instead of a user/name password object here is a sample in php https://github.com/sinch/php-auth-ticket

Comment: Hello, I tried this, but nothing changed:

require_once("SinchTicketGenerator.php");

$generator = new SinchTicketGenerator('key', 'secret');
$signedUserTicket = $generator->generateTicket('peter', new DateTime(), 3600);

Comment: Did you change in the client side to to supply that ticket?

Comment: What do you mean, I placed the code mentioned above:

 require_once("SinchTicketGenerator.php"); $generator = new SinchTicketGenerator('key', 'secret'); $signedUserTicket = $generator->generateTicket('peter', new DateTime(), 3600);